# Add ellipsis with substring_index MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string, substring

Is it possible to add ellipsis after the MySQL `substring_index` function?

So if I have the following code:

```
SET @string = "abc, def, ghi, jkl, mno";

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(@string, ', ', 3);
```

The result is: `abc, def, ghi`

So is it possible to add `...` at the back ONLY when it is cut? 
I wish to retrieve this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(@string, ', ', 3);
---> RESULT: abc, def, ghi...

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(@string, ', ', 5);
---> RESULT: abc, def, ghi, jkl, mno
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some conditional logic:

```
select (case when @string = substring_index(@string, ', ', 3)
             then substring_index(@string, ', ', 3)
             else concat(substring_index(@string, ', ', 3), '...')
        end)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I was afraid that it would slow down my query (since it is a huge query in my project) but it doesn't! Perfect!